# Python CSV.reader skipping the last column

Tags: python, csv

Having a weird problem in csv reader.

Here's my csv list in order. 'virgil' has 3 items and is after 'maria'

_timesheet.csv (omitted)

```
maria,2018-02-08 20:30:04.180000,45.0
maria,2018-02-15 20:30:04.180000,45.0
maria,2018-02-22 20:30:04.180000,45.0
maria,2018-03-01 20:30:04.180000,45.0
virgil,2018-02-08 20:30:04.180000,45.0
virgil,2018-02-15 20:24:41.264000,45.0
virgil,2018-02-22 20:24:41.264000,45.0
virgil,2018-03-01 20:24:41.264000,45.0
```

but when I process it, the result becomes this and causes an index out of range.

```
['merry', '2018-02-08 09:09:09.315000', '45.0']
['merry', '2018-02-15 09:09:09.315000', '45.0']
['merry', '2018-02-22 09:09:09.315000', '45.0']
['merry', '2018-03-01 09:09:09.315000', '45.0']
['virgil', '2018-02-08 09:09:09.3150']
IndexError: timesheetF[2] index out of range
```

'merry' is positioned farther away but in the process, it becomes next to it.

Any process I'm missing? below is my code

```
_resources = list(csv.reader(open("raw/resources.csv", 'rb')))
_timesheets = list(csv.reader(open("raw/_timesheet.csv", 'rb')))
for resource in _resources:
    for timesheetF in _timesheets:
        res_row = []
        if(resource[0] == timesheetF[0]):

            res_row.append(resource[0])

            if 'philippines' in resource[1].lower():
                res_row.append("Manila")
            else:
                res_row.append(resource[1])

            #Active
            if 'true' in resource[2].lower():
                res_row.append("Yes")
            else:
                res_row.append("No")

             if 'kronos' in resource[3].lower():
                res_row.append("KRO")
            elif 'avenew' in resource[3].lower():
                res_row.append("POS")
            elif 'hcm' in resource[3].lower():
                res_row.append("LND")
            else:
                res_row.append(resource[3])

            if 'support and maintenance' in resource[4].lower():
                res_row.append("AM")
            elif 'development' in resource[4].lower():
                res_row.append("AD")
            elif 'admin' in resource[4].lower():
                res_row.append("Admin")

            res_row.append(timesheetF[2]) ###### ERROR HERE ###
            results.writerow(res_row)
```

Comment: are you sure you are processing the file you think you are?  are you sure you don't have a "virgil" element with only 2 cells in your file after the "merry" elements?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure there isn't an invisible character of some sort in there (though that would usually be either visible on printing the row `list`, or trigger an error in `csv.reader`)? Or more likely, some code that is altering `_timesheets` or `timesheetF` that you haven't shown us? If you don't provide a [MCVE], we can't really help.

Comment: the timesheet you show isn't the same piece thats loaded in that list

Comment: error was from a different part of the code. thanks so much these helped me eliminate possible errors faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the _timesheet.csv file, my best guess is that one of the rows in your timesheet csv file only contains 2 fields when it normally should have 3.

The error is informing you that index 2 is outside the range of available values for the current timesheetF being processed. I would try and figure out which row in _timesheet.csv is the one causing the error before proceeding.

You could put in a try/except statement around the res_row.append(timesheetF[2]) line and print out what that timesheetF value is to help debug the issue.

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested and found the error from a different part of the code. Thanks so much, i'll remember to try these stuffs next time~